# Views exposed filter in block redirects to homepage instead of current page

Tags: 7, views, redirection

Problem is similar to `drupal.org/node/1807916` #65.

I'm using Views ("7.x-3.6+4-dev" in D7.21) exposed filter in bartik, with my filter exposed as block in sidebar. When I click the reset button I am redirected to homepage instead of current page as desired.

URL shown:

> "localhost/?field_sku_value=123&field_name_value=&field_component_value=&op=Reset"

(last filter values)

Filter exposed on Views Page is ok.

Try to tweak `$form_state['redirect']` in `views_plugin_exposed_form.inc` doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Same here. I am having a views content pane with views attachment und exposed filters within a block on a user profile page. The filters working correctly and are staying on the same page, but the reset button redirects to the frontpage.

Comment: AJAX option on?

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery fix for this issue.  See https://drupal.org/node/1109980, #23.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is rendered inside a panel, you can choose the option "Use Panel path" in the pane settings of your view display.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from https://www.drupal.org/node/1264316#comment-6930726 worked for me. Just copy the views-exposed-form.tpl.php to views-exposed-form--block.tpl.php from views module folder to your template folder and change the reset button code to:

```
<?php if (!empty($reset_button)): ?>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-reset-button">
        <input type="reset" id="edit-reset" onclick="history.go(0)" name="op" value="Reset" class="form-submit">
      </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```